# Написание названий городов.

Tags: согласование

Как правильно согласовывать названия городов в подобных случаях: Комплекс в г. Калуга (е), открытие магазина в г. Смоленск (е), УФМС г. Трубчевск (а), вблизи г. Москвы (а) и т.п. И ещё: красиво ли писать названия городов без слова "город" (недалеко от Брянска....)?

Answer (score 4):

Писать название городов без слова "город" гораздо красивее и естественнее, но в канцелярском стиле пишут с "г.".

При склонении подвергаются изменению обе части *в городе Москве,  УФМС города Трубчевска, комплекс в городе Калуге*. Исключение: если название города не склоняется ; *в городе Сочи*.

Comment: Спасибо!Я задалась эти вопросом потому, что в паспорте (там, где указывается, кто выдал)обнаружила написание города без изменений:УФМС России по Брянской области в г. Трубчевск. Получается, это некорректное написание?

Comment: Это уже хорошо прижившийся канцелярит, у которого тоже есть своя логика (понятней название). Думаю в не столь далеком будущем подобное написание перестанет противоречить нормам литературного языка, но пока ещё этого не произошло.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мне очень помогли. Вот так иногда простые вещи заводят в тупик)

Answer (score 3):

(прошу не принимать как ответ, это развернутый комментарий)

> Получается, это некорректное написание?

С точки зрения литературного русского - да, не совсем корректное.
Но в канцелярском стиле до некоторой степени оправдано. Именно в сочетании с сокращением "г.".  Аналогичные подходы (и даже более широко) используют военные. Это терпимо. Плохо, когда распространяется на разговорную речь - причем довольно агрессивно...

Вообще ворос этот не так прост, как может показаться.

Есть случаи, когда топонимы сами по себе не склоняются, но это трдуно установить без специальных словарей. Поэтому тенденция к несклонению прогрессирует. Приходится мириться.

Кроме того, современные правила (вернее сказать - авторитетные рекомендации) предусматривают некоторые отступления от правила склонения, если название образовано от собственного имени или созвучно с ним. Например - для топонимов на -но/-во (Пушкино). Впрочем, на эти случаи тоже есть возражения.

Comment: Спасибо! А как Вы думаете, в рекламе лучше всё же склонять, да?

Comment: Я имела в виду, в рекламных модулях, при создании рекламных текстов)

Answer (score 3):

Я за то, чтобы склонять всегда. Но вот как раз в рекламе от правил частенько сознательно отступают. Такой прием заставляет читающего дольше задержать внимание на самой рекламе. Только не переборщите.

А касательно конкретно городов - пишите без этого г. и склоняйте.
Если только это не полный почтовый адрес, его просто стоит всегда писать в именительном падеже, исключая всякие вопросы о склонении.

Comment: А если это такой текст рекламы: "В связи с открытием нового магазина в г. Калуге....." и подобные этому? У нас в редакции принято писать с "г."

Comment: Ну что делать, если в редакции исповедуют канцелярит?!  
Пишите с "г." и склоняйте.